# validation rule conditional formulas

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule, conditional, contracts

I need to create a validation rule on standard object "Contract" that will fire on standard Activate Button, the formula will:

```
If(status != 'Activated' && DateOne == Null, && DateTwo == null && Recordtype == 'Two'){
   Mesage("please fillout the dates and make sure Record Type = One");
}
If(status != 'Activated' && DateOne != Null, && DateTwo != null && Recordtype == 'Two'){
   msg("please select record type one");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two separate `Validation Rules`. You specify the `Error Message` separately from the `Error Condition Formula`.

One of your criteria seems wrong, because when exactly one of the date fields is null, neither rule applies. Based on the error messages in your post, I assume you meant if *either* date is null and the `Status` is not yet `'Activated'`, then the `RecordType` must still be `'One'`. Currently you only do the validation if *both* dates are null.

You should also explicitly ensure the `RecordType` is still `'One'` if that is your intention. Right now there may only be two possible values, but that can change.

**Inactive Either Null Rule Criteria**

```
AND(
    Status != 'Activated',
    RecordType.Name != 'One',
    OR(Date1__c = null, Date2__c = null)
)
```

**Inactive Neither Null Rule Criteria**

```
AND(
    Status != 'Activated',
    RecordType.Name != 'One',
    Date1__c != null,
    Date2__c != null
)
```

Comment: the 1st one works just fine. Thanks.